# How to specify build target in kaniko for multi-stage Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, kaniko

I'm looking for a way to define a specific build target for multi-stage Dockerfile in Kaniko.

I have Dockerfile that has several stages. I can build a specific stage with docker build --target. Can I do the same with Kaniko?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be `--target`, which is in the README but is better described in the [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/253).